# TDOA using 4 latitude/longitude points?

Tags: python

I am working on the TDOA problem with latitude and longitude coordinates, following the literature of [https://inside.mines.edu/~whereman/papers/Murphy-Hereman-Trilateration-1995.pdf](https://inside.mines.edu/%7Ewhereman/papers/Murphy-Hereman-Trilateration-1995.pdf) . However, for 2 coordinates of latitude and longitude, I have implemented the following code and am checking the error that I may have for each point within the selected grid of latitude (0, -20) and longitude (-70, -50). However, the obtained error is not what was expected

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#position sensor´s
X = np.array([-67.02, -55.09, -58.28, -65.51])
Y= np.array([-5.39, -12.79, -3.79, -13.56])


def dis(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
pi2 = np.pi/2
rad = np.pi/180
grd = 180/np.pi
degtokm = 111.195

latnp = pi2        #Latitude of North Pole

lon0 = lon1*rad
loo1 = lon2*rad

lat0 = lat1*rad
laa1 = lat2*rad


c1 = loo1-lon0

if c1 != 0:
    c1=1./np.tan(c1/2.)

    lla1=laa1-lat0
    llb1=laa1+lat0
    
    if lla1 != 0:
        
        yxa1=c1*np.sin(lla1/2.)/np.cos(llb1/2.)
        yxb1=c1*np.cos(lla1/2.)/np.sin(llb1/2.)

        yxa1=np.arctan(yxa1)
        yxb1=np.arctan(yxb1)

        r1=np.tan(lla1/2.)*np.sin(yxb1)/np.sin(yxa1)
        r1=np.arctan(r1)*2.
        
    if lla1 == 0:
        lla1=latnp-laa1
        c1 = loo1-lon0
        r1=np.sin(c1)*np.sin(lla1)
        r1=np.arcsin(r1)
if c1 == 0: 
    r1=abs(laa1-lat0)

r1=r1*grd  # Conversion a grados

r1=abs(r1*degtokm)   # Conversion a km

return r1
```

In the time function, I added a random error of 20 microseconds

```
def tiempo(yr, xr, Ye, Xe, j):

mean, std = 0, 20e-6                        # mean and standard deviation
delta_t = np.random.normal(mean, std, 400)  # random values
delta_t = delta_t.reshape(100,4)            

c = 300000                                  # Speed of Light 3x10´5 km/s

d1 = dis(yr, xr, Ye[0], Xe[0])
d2 = dis(yr, xr, Ye[1], Xe[1])
d3 = dis(yr, xr, Ye[2], Xe[2])
d4 = dis(yr, xr, Ye[3], Xe[3])


time = np.asarray([d1,d2,d3,d4])/c + delta_t[j,:]

return time
```

With the distance function and time, I obtain the theoretical time values, and with them, simulate the position using the code

```
def linearize(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,d1,d2,d3,d4):

A = np.array([[x2 - x1, y2 - y1],   # Sensitivity matrix
              [x3 - x1, y3 - y1],
              [x4 - x1, y4 - y1]])

b = (np.array([[d1**2 - d2**2 + (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2],   # Data matrix
               [d1**2 - d3**2 + (x3-x1)**2 + (y3-y1)**2],
               [d1**2 - d4**2 + (x4-x1)**2 + (y4-y1)**2]]))/2

# Solution : 

B = np.dot(A.T,A)
C = np.linalg.inv(B)  #  Finding the inverse of Matrix A

D = np.dot(C,A.T)

p0 = np.asarray([[x1],[y1]])

x, y = np.dot(D,b) + p0


return x, y
```

To obtain the error in each value

```
def main(yr, xr, ry, rx, j):

time = tiempo(yr, xr, ry, rx, j) 

c = 300000                    # Speed of Light 3x10´5 km/s


# Distance d1, d2, d3 ....

N = 1 / 111.195       

# CConversion from kilometers to degrees  

d1 = time[0] * c * N
d2 = time[1] * c * N
d3 = time[2] * c * N 
d4 = time[3] * c * N

# Coordinates of the sensors: 
x1, x2, x3, x4 = rx[0], rx[1], rx[2], rx[3]
y1, y2, y3, y4 = ry[0], ry[1], ry[2], ry[3]


# Finding x, y.

x, y = linearize(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,d1,d2,d3,d4)

# Error

e = dis(yr,xr,y,x)

return e
```

100 simulations averaged to obtain the error matrix (v_er)

```
v_er = np.zeros([21,21])

xr, yr = -70, 0
for i in range(0,21):
    yr = 0
    yr = yr - i

    for j in range(0,21):
        xr = -70
        xr = xr + j
    
        er = np.zeros(100)
    
        for k in range(0,100):
            er[k] = main(yr, xr, Y, X, k)
        
    v_er[i,j] = np.mean(er)
```

The error values that I obtain with my code with error 20 micro-seg

https://ibb.co/TrxLG59

https://ibb.co/4FRkYHM

Expected outcome

would like to know what the error in my code would be